# How should I connect a braided shield 2-core cable with a headphone plug with three cores

Tags: audio, cables, grounding, shielding, headphones

I'm a beginner in Electronics.

The cable has two cores and a braided shield. What should I do about the ground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume your jack is a stereo one, like on this picture:

[image]

Cable shield goes to ground (see pic) and left/right signal wires go to the two smaller lugs.